# cPanel MySQL Service Manager down but /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid is running

Tags: mysql, cpanel, centos7.6

I recently updated my version of cPanel to v78.0.17 and upgraded MySQL from 5.6 to 5.7.

I had some errors during the startup of the MySQL server which I resolved by running the cPanel MySQL/MariaDB Upgrade a second time.

From what I can see the MySQL is running and operating as expected. However I am now receiving cPanel Notifications from Service Manager (tailwatchd) that the MySQL service is down.

```
root@hostname [~]# ps faux |grep -i mysql
root     16516  0.0  0.0 112708   996 pts/0    S+   11:05   0:00  |       \_ grep --color=auto -i mysql
mysql    15308  1.5  0.2 1310132 82508 ?       Sl   11:02   0:02 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

extract from /var/log/chkservd.log

```
mysql [[check command:-][check command output:(XID 4jtb2a) The “mysql” service is down: mysqladmin: [ERROR] unknown variable 'pass=xxxxxxxx'

The subprocess “/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_mysql” reported error number 255 when it ended.][socket connect:N/A][fail count:66]Restarting mysql....
[notify:failed service:mysql]]...
```

I have found this link on the cPanel Forum https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/tailwatch-service-manager-has-stopped-monitoring-mysql.648093/#post-2643253 however I do not see the fix.

Can anyone shed light on a possible fix for this?

Comment: what is the content of your `/root/.my.cnf` ?

Comment: Check `/var/lib/mysql`, there should be a file with the server name ending in `.err`. Check the contents of that file and see why MySQL is not starting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the /root/.my.cnf file.

MySQL 5.6 allows the property 'pass' while MySQL 5.7 requires the property 'password'

The upgrade process in cPanel (MySQL/MariaDB Upgrade) does not update/correct this file.

MySQL 5.6 (pre MySQL 5.7)

```
[client]
user=root
pass='xxxxx'
```

MySQL 5.7

```
[client]
user=root
password='xxxxx'
```

Thanks to cPanel Support for solving this issue.